# Add .jpg extension to image-urls without extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, reddit, imgur

I get url-images from imgur with `'href': article.data.url,` (ex: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMz26.jpg)

But some times I get these urls-images without **.jpg** extension (ex: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0Iaq.jpg)

So, I would like to convert any url-image-without-extension (or not ending in .jpg) to the format `http://i.imgur.com/<ID>.jpg`

(ex: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0Iaq.jpg --> becomes --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVPsu.jpg)

What I would have to change on code to fix this?

Here the code I used to resolve URLs images:

```
// getting image URLs
App.image_domains = {
    'i.imgur.com': function (article) {
        var url = article.data.url;
        var split_url = url.split("imgur.com/");
        if (split_url[1].indexOf(".") === -1) {
            return url + ".jpg";
        }
        return url;

    },
    'imgur.com': function (article) {
        var url = article.data.url;

        // Ignore album images
        if (url.indexOf("/a/") !== -1) {
            return "";
        }

        // Remove unnecessary paths from image URLs
        url = url.replace(/(www\.)?imgur.com/, "i.imgur.com");
        url = url.replace(/\/r\/[^\/]+/, "");
        url = url.replace("/new", "");
        url = url.replace("/gallery", "");

        // Make sure the URL doesnt already have an extension
        var split_url = url.split("imgur.com/");
        if (split_url[1].indexOf(".") === -1) {
            url += ".jpg";
        }

        return url;
    }
};
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: you have done a good job outlining your goals, but not the problems you are having

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is - http://jsfiddle.net/aimeeborda/aX6Te/where I filter for img's src

```
(.jpg|.png)$
```

that do not end with jpg or png and add the extension

```
var index = src.lastIndexOf('.') < 0 ? src.length : src.lastIndexOf('.');
$(this).attr('src', src.substring(0, index) + ".jpg");
```